# DynaLoader version issue in perl script

Tags: perl

I'm getting following error while trying to run my perl script. Please can someone assist?

```
[eambtchd@nykdsr000000900:~/stage4/nyfeamld/EAMBatch/apps/default_ol/loader/bin$> perl rmOldRecord.pl ord.pl
DynaLoader object version 1.10 does not match $DynaLoader::VERSION 1.04 at /home/eambtchd/stage4/nyfeamld/EAMBatch/site_perl/5.8.0/i386-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 105.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib64/perl5/DBI.pm line 157.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib64/perl5/DBI.pm line 157.
Compilation failed in require at rmOldRecord.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at rmOldRecord.pl line 6.
```

Answer (score 4):

You're loading the Perl component of the DynaLoader from one version of Perl and the binary component of a different version. You have a bad install of DynaLoader, which means you have a bad install of Perl.

Comment: +1 To troubleshoot, perhaps add the (pertinent parts of) the output from `perl -V`.